How to properly set cookies in cURL requests using Node.js?
I’m trying to make a cURL request from Node.js but cannot set cookies correctly. The same cURL command works in Postman, but in Node.js, I get an unauthorized response.
I’m using the fetch method to make the request and manually setting the Cookie header. Despite matching the Postman headers, I still get the unauthorized error.
Are there any specific techniques or libraries in Node.js to handle cookies better? Is there a way to directly use cURL from Node.js?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This involved cookie trasmitted between Curl and Node.js. You can use curl to complete the authorization and save the cookie to a file , then pass it to Node.js
Syntax like "curl -b from_nodejs_cookie -c to_nodejs_cookie"
Then load to_nodejs_cookie in your node.js code
